# When to use "tratar de" and when to use "intentar" for "to try to"?

Tags: sinónimos, selección-de-palabras

Spanish has three words that can translate to English `to try`.

`Probar` is easy to remember because it's used for `sample` or `taste`, like:

> Have you ever tried tacos el pastor?

But I never know when to use `tratar de` or `intentar`. Just now I wanted to write `I will try to come to the next meeting` and used `intentar` but when I checked with Google Translate it used `tratar de`.

Which word works best for this use and are there some guidelines about when each is appropriate, or are they interchangeable synonyms?

Comment: There's also *procurar*.

Comment: In almost all senses they are interchangeable, particularly in daily speech. `Tratar de` is most common, except for tasting something; `probar` must be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that they are synonyms, but not in all cases. So I'd distinguish several meanings of try:

- Taste, sample, or otherwise test in order to determine strength, effect, worth, or desirability.

In that meaning the only possibility is "**Probar**".

> E.g. I have never tried the Spanish omelette.
>   Nunca he **probado** la tortilla de patata.
>
> E.g. You can try the car to check it's worth it.
>   Puedes **probar** el coche para comprobar que merece la pena.

- To make an effort; strive; endeavor.

In this case it would be translated as "**intentar**", "**tratar de**", "**procurar**"; but **not as "probar a"**.

> E.g. They tried to win the match but they couldn't.
>
> **Intentaron** ganar el partido pero no pudieron.
>
> **Trataron de** ganar el partido pero no pudieron.
>
> **Procuraron** ganar el partido pero no pudieron.

- To attempt, to have a go

It can be translated as "**intentar**", "**tratar de**" or "**probar a**".

> E.g. As he couldn't open the front door he tried to open the back door.
>
> Como no podía abrir la puerta delantera **intentó** abrir la puerta trasera.
>
> Como no podía abrir la puerta delantera **trató de** abrir la puerta trasera.
>
> Como no podía abrir la puerta delantera **probó a** abrir la puerta trasera.

Comment: "Nunca he `probado` la tortilla de patata." - For some reason I want to translate this as "I have never `tasted` a Spanish Omelette."

Comment: @Serdar, I would say "I have never tried..." and "I have never tasted..."  would both be correct translations for "Nunca he probado..." when speaking of a food.

Comment: I cannot understand clearly the difference between "to make an effort" and "to attempt". I'd use both "to make an effort/strive to win the game" and "to attempt to win the game" Does the former imply bigger dedication than the latter?

Answer (score 3):

Not all of what has been said previously, has been absolutely correct in terms of Tratar and Intentar.

- ***Probar*** has a very clear difference and has been elucidated and made distinct very well. Probar is used for testing out, trying food, trying on clothes, for example.
- ***Tratar*** is to try to do something, to attempt, have a go at, and also means to treat, as in the manner of behaviour you exhibit to a person.
- ***Intentar*** is to intend to, to mean to do something.

It is a subtle difference, but with *tratar*, to try to do something is to make the attempt (when used in the present tense), whereas with *intentar*, it is to have the intention of doing it while used in the present tense, and not necessarily be engaged in actively doing it.

*Intentar* in the present tense is more closely equivalent to *tratar* in the future tense (although there is a nuance and it is not entirely the same). For example,

> "I intend to go to the party" = "I will try to go to the party".
>
> "Intento ir a la fiesta" o "Trataré de ir a la fiesta".

Note Tratar requires the "de" after, Intentar does not.

How people actually use the verbs, however, is not necessarily reflective of their actual meaning.

In simple terms:

- ***Probar*** = to test / try out
- ***Tratar*** = to try (to do something) / to attempt / to treat (someone in a certain manner)
- ***Intentar*** = to have the intent to / to mean to / to be going to be attempting to / to be expecting to be making the effort to do something with uncertainty as to the actual outcome

Comment: So what would give words their meaning other than how people use them?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Google translation, you will notice all these alternatives are offered for the beginning of the sentence:

- Voy a tratar de
- Voy a intentar
- Trataré de
- Intentaré
- Trataré (*wrong*)

So, for this usage, **intentar** and **tratar de** are synonymous. Of course there might be regional preferences for any of the 4 ways to write it, but they all mean exactly the same and will be understood by everyone.

Comment: And of course we can't always trust Google Translate's expertise so I'd like to hear from our experts here too who are not computers (-:

Comment: Well, how can you be sure I'm not a computer? :-D   Google is right in this case, except for the one I pointed out.

Comment: as @hippietrail mentioned: machine translator engines are not an argument when you learn the language. when you need to translate a sentence - it is ok. But when people start their answer with "but Google Translate" - it is already a good reason to skip the whole answer. Because machine translation has other goals. And if you are a computer - I'm going to skip your answer, because machines still (2023) can not really handle natural languages grammar well.